# What are the rules regarding return types that pass or fail when used with assignment in an if statement in php?

Tags: php

After an exhaustive search for internet references about the rules for doing assignments in if statements. About all I can find here is that you should never, never, never, ever use them. Because it leads to massive errors and drastic consequences. However, I went through a ton of lines of code with some of the composer packages, and apparently it's not that frowned upon there.

I'm just not sure what the return type must be for the assignment to be counted as false. Does it need to be just a falsey value like 0 or "", or should it be something like null? Does an empty array get counted as false for assignment?

EDIT:
example

```
if(!$new_invoice=ConvInvoice::createNewInvoice()){
    error_log("Whoopsie!");
}
else {
    //Do processing for with invoice....
}
```

in ConvInvoice class

```
public function __construct($data){

   //Data processing and record creation...

   if($record_error){
        return 0; //or null, or whatever
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of this? What I’m picturing is something like `if( $bar = foo() ) { // do something }`, which looks more like a typo than intended functionality. I could see something like `if( !$bar = foo() ) { throw new Exception('oopsie'); }`, in which any falsey return would trigger the exception...  I think. This is similar to the frequently used approach of assigning a database fetch in a while statement.  Best course of action would be to set up unit tests to verify the scenarios in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the manual, the expression is [converted into a boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

When converting to boolean, [the following values are considered FALSE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

```
◦   the boolean FALSE itself
◦   the integers 0 and -0 (zero)
◦   the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
◦   the empty string, and the string "0"
◦   an array with zero elements
◦   the special type NULL (including unset variables)
◦   SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
```

Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource and NAN).

> Warning
>   -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!